# Cypress not saving into localstorage

Tags: javascript, authentication, local-storage, cypress

I'm testing a working web SPA with Cypress, using cypress-localstorage-commands.

```
before(() => {
    cy.clearLocalStorageSnapshot();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });
```

On the first section of code, inside the first "it" I'm just logging into my system by clicking on the different data fields and accessing the section of the web that I'm interested in.

```
it('Open Simulations', () => {
      cy.visit('/') //Loads the first page
      cy.get('button[id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click() //Accepts Cookies
      cy.get('.input-box-main-field.required').type('mockuser') //Type the user
      cy.get('input[type=password]').type('mockpwd{enter}') //Type the password
      cy.get('.spinner').should('not.exist') //waits until loading spinner is gone
      cy.visit('/simulacion/nueva') //opens simulations
      cy.scrollTo('right') //scrolls to simular travel button
      cy.get('.sc-EHOje.fgNeQB').eq(7).click() //Clicks on simular
      cy.get('.spinner').should('not.exist') //waits until loading spinner is gone
    })
```

After this a screen will appear waiting for data submission, this screen needs 4 different data: Destination, Amount of passengers, Date of arrival, Date of Departure.

```
it('Fill Simulation', () => {
      
      cy.get('.input-box-main-field').contains('Seleccione un destino de viaje').click()//opens drop down menu
      cy.get('ul>li').eq(0).click()//selects 1st element aka Spain
      cy.get('.input-box-main-field.required').type('2')//Setting pasenger number
      cy.get('.input-box-main-field').eq(3).type(dayjs().format('DD/MM/YYYY'))// settign todays date as return
      cy.get('.main-button-text').contains('CONTINUAR').click()//Continue
      cy.get('.spinner').should('not.exist')
    })
```

After this, the app will validate the data fields and then send the API a post request with the data, so an estimate may be returned.
When testing this by myself there is no problem, the post request goes through and I get my result back. When doing it through this Cypress code a problem appears, the auth key is missing, so my backend won't allow me to make a post request.
I've no idea why this is happening, the auth key is stored on LocalStorage.

Comment: Cypress clears local storage before every test. Also it's an anti pattern to have tests depend on each other, the ordering shouldn't matter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for you answer. First would you mind explaining how my tests depend on each other? One access a fucntionality and the other fills it, IMO.
As for the second part, I've tried this, to no avail.
`code`
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
      preserve: 'OptanonAlertBoxClosed',
      preserve: 'OptanonConsent',
      preserve: "LocalStorage"
    }) `code`

Comment: Yes, and that's precisely _how_ they depend on each other. The second one is only expected to pass if run directly after the first one.

Comment: Local storage isn't a cookie, and also that object only contains `{ preserve: "LocalStorage" }` because you can't have multiple properties with the same name. You're going to have a very hard time using Cypress if you're not comfortable with basic JS.

Comment: Great, thanks, I do understand now. They will be included into the same test, but my problem prevails.
I've tried inserting a wait command for 10s in the middle of the test just so I can open a terminal and make use of console.log(LocalStorage) but no matter at which point of the test I do so, it's empty. Even when both tests are now inside a single one

Comment: Then please give a [mre] of something that _could_ work, because what you're showing right now definitely won't https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-do-I-preserve-cookies-localStorage-in-between-my-tests

Comment: You are totally right about the JS and cookies, it was a quick attempt with little thinking behind it. I've also attempted to do so: `  before(() => {
    cy.clearLocalStorageSnapshot();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });
`

Comment: Then I'd guess you're also using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands, which isn't mentioned in the question, but 1. you don't seem to be restoring the saved cookies; and 2. hacking around the problem to allow your tests to be interdependent isn't a real solution, and doesn't explain why it didn't work in a single test. [Edit] the question.

Comment: You are totally right, I was working on the minimal reproducible example but then I saw you response mentioning I didn't restore the saved localstorage, total gaffe on my side.
Now it's working but still as you said it's a hack around the problem. @jonrsharpe

Comment: The solution to my problem, adding the following code by cypress-localstorage-commands before declaring the tests.
`before(() => {
    cy.clearLocalStorageSnapshot();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.restoreLocalStorage();
  });`